# Python: How to transform a block of strings into one line

Tags: python

This is the text block that I want to transform to another form:

```
1040 S. Vintage Ave.
Building A Ontario, CA 91761
United States
```

This is the wanted output:

```
1040 S. Vintage Ave., Building A Ontario, CA 91761,United States
```

I've tried to use split, and replace, also some re expression but I couldn't make it work.

Any suggestion would be helpful :)

Comment: `multiline_string.replace('\n', ' ')` ?

Comment: Is the text block in a file or jsut a string?

Comment: @han solo's suggestion will work, except just replace the empty char `' '` to `', '` within the argument list of the replace method.

Comment: @Stefan see if the answer posted below helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering the block text is in a file:

list.txt:

```
1040 S. Vintage Ave.

Building A Ontario, CA 91761
United States
```

and then:

```
logFile = "list.txt"
with open(logFile) as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# you may also want to remove empty lines
content = [l.strip() for l in content if l.strip()]

lastLine = content[-1]

   for line in content:
    findComma = line.find(",")
    if findComma > 0:
        print(line.split(",")[0] + ", ", end = "")
        print(line.split(",")[1] + ", ", end = "")
    else:
        if line != lastLine:
            print(line + ", ", end = "")
        else:
            print(line, end = "")
```

OUTPUT:

```
1040 S. Vintage Ave., Building A Ontario,  CA 91761, United States
```

Answer (score 1):

multiline_string.replace('\n', ' ') 
or split by '\n' and join with empty char ('')

Answer (score 1):

If your text is in a variable called `text`:

```
one_line = text.replace("\n", ", ")
```

That replaces the end of each line with a comma, putting it all on one line.